# PS1 Customization

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

Just a quick one.

Trying to modify my PS1 to show just a specific number of chracters.

Currently :

user@domain.co.uk@linuxhostname

This is because I have just intergrated some systems in my environment which allow a windows user to log into a linux environment using windows ceredntials. Hense the double domain.

I want to remove everything after the first @ symbol, which currently fits in the \u switch.

Is there a way to tell the \u switch to only use say the first 4 characters of the user-name. So instead of "user@domain.co.uk", I get just "user", ultimalty getting user@linuxhost?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this on my Mint 19.2 system, and it *should* give you want you want. Replace the `\u` in your .bashrc with `${LOGNAME:0:4}`, then resource it.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go and let you know.

Comment: `${LOGNAME:0:4}` does match the OP's request for "the first 4 characters of the user-name", but `${LOGNAME%%@*}` would make more sense in general.

Comment: Ok so I took your example and researched a little more. Replacing \u with ${USER::-13}         This removed the last 13 characters from the end of the username and returned user@linuxhostname as required. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing \u with ${USER::-13} This removed the last 13 characters from the end of the username and returned user@linuxhostname as required.